# Rendering a ModelForm within a Modal & Handling Errors

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have a view, `item_list_view` that responds to GET requests by rendering a template, `mainlist.html`. That template renders a list of items along with links to edit those items:

```
#mainlist.html
{% for item in items %}
    <a class='edit-link' href='#' data-form="{% url items:itemform %}?i={{item.id}}">
        Edit
    </a>
{% endfor %}

<!-- later in mainlist.html -->
<div class='modal fade' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id='itemFormModal' style='display:none;'>
</div>
```

When an edit link is clicked, the modal is loaded with content using the corresponding `data-form` attribute, then the modal is shown:

```
$(".edit-link").click(function(ev){ 
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).data("form"); 
    $("#itemFormModal").load(url, function() { 
        $(this).modal('show'); 
    });
    return false; //prevent click propogation
});
```

At this point the modal is displayed with the appropriate ModelForm, and that form has class `item-form`. We submit the form via ajax:

```
$(".item-form").on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        context: this,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $('#itemFormModal').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This works fine if the form is submitted with valid data. After a successful form submission, the user is redirected back to the list view along with a success message.

If there are errors with the form, I would like the form to be re-rendered with those errors in that original modal. However, right now if I submit a form with errors my browser goes directly to the action URL where the form is rendered with errors.

How can I re-load my ModelForm, with errors, into this modal rather than being redirected?

---

Edit: when an edit link is clicked this view:

```
def litem_create_edit_view(request):
    #Displays a ModelForm for an Item object 
    #if an "instance" is passed via the url, that 
    #instance is loaded into the ModelForm for editing
    instance_id = request.GET.get('instance', None)
    if instance_id is not None:
        instance = Item.objects.get(id=instance_id)
    else:
        instance = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            newitem = form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Item saved!")
            return redirect("items:mainlist")

    else:
        form = LeadForm(instance=instance)

    return render(request, "leads/leadform.html", {'form':form, 'instance':instance})
```

Renders this template inside the modal:

```
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    {% if instance %}
    <form method="post" class='lead-form' action="{% url 'leads:leadform' %}?instance={{instance.id}}">
    {% else %}
    <form method="post" class='lead-form' action="{% url 'leads:leadform' %}">
    {% endif %}
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        {% if instance %}
        <h3>Editing Item</h3>
        {% else %}
        <h3>Add Item</h3>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form|crispy }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
           <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view use something like:

```
foos  = Foo.objects.all() # or any other model data you want to return
data = serializers.serialize('json', foos) # serialize it
```

and return JSON and not the template:

```
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

So this way you stay within the same div without being redirected, just the data
is consumed and rendered.

Comment: Is there a way to return a rendered template rather than JSON? The initial GET request made to `{% url items:itemform %}?i={{item.id}}` when an edit link is clicked responds with a `return render(...)` to render a template inside the modal with the correct model instance loaded. Ideally I would like to be able to re-render that same template when I hit a form error, since the template it uses is ready to handle displaying those errors.

Comment: If you return template than you need to provide your entire form is within the div that has to stay intact - as the entire modal window will be reloaded.

Comment: I added some info to my original question; the view does return the full form & template when it encounters an invalid submission. I get what you're saying about staying within the same div (the concept anyway), I just thought that the current view would accomplish that since it executes the same `render` block both for a GET request and in response to invalid form data.

Comment: So what you can do is to make all scenarios go to return render but add errors as part of the dictionary instead of Django form validation having a separate redirect. Just add more messages to the dictionary within render like {'form':form, 'instance':instance,'error1':error1} and then use {{ error1 }}